# Retornar objetos somados de um array em um só

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Seguinte, sou designer e estou aprendendo javascript aos poucos.
Uma das coisas que tenho mais dificuldades, são objetos e arrays, por isso to focando mais nisso agora. Tenho um array com 4 objetos como o código a seguir.

```
var players = [{
  name: "Batman",
  id: "1",
  points: 10
},
{
  name: "Superman",
  id: "2",
  points: 10
},
{
  name: "Batman",
  id: "1",
  points: 10
},
{
  name: "Superman",
  id: "2",
  points: 5
}
];
```

O que eu preciso: retornar os objetos com as mesmas ids's e os points somados, resultando em 2 objetos.

Qual a lógica que eu uso pra resolver esse problema? Como juntar os objetos com a mesma id e somar os points de cada um? Já consegui fazer só com 1 objeto, mas estava comparando com a id. Se eu tivesse um array bem maior, seria quase inviável ficar comparando um por um. Quero entender a lógica aplicada nesse contexto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens várias maneiras, sugestões:

#### Cria um novo objeto com um `for`:

```js
var players = [{
    name: "Batman",
    id: "1",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    id: "2",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Batman",
    id: "1",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    id: "2",
    points: 5
  }
];

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var id = players[i].id;
  if (!obj[id]) obj[id] = players[i]; // caso ainda não haja um objeto com essa ID
  else obj[id].points += players[i].points;
}

console.log(obj);
```

#### Usa o `.reduce()`:

```js
var players = [{
    name: "Batman",
    id: "1",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    id: "2",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Batman",
    id: "1",
    points: 10
  },
  {
    name: "Superman",
    id: "2",
    points: 5
  }
];
var obj = players.reduce(function(obj, player) {
  if (!obj[player.id]) obj[player.id] = player; // caso ainda não haja um objeto com essa ID
  else obj[player.id].points += player.points;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Eu segui esses dois exemplos seu porém o array ao invés de retornar com index, ta retornando com o ID de cada objeto.